# How do I correctly plot the clusters produced from a cluster analysis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot

I want to carry out hierarchical clustering in Matlab and plot the clusters on a scatterplot. I have used the `evalclusters` function to first investigate what a 'good' number of clusters would be using different criteria values eg Silhouette, `CalinskiHarabasz`. Here is the code I used for the evaluation (`x` is my data with 200 observations and 10 variables):

```
E = evalclusters(x,'linkage','CalinskiHarabasz','KList',[1:10])
%store kmean optimal clusters
optk=E.OptimalK;
%save the outouts to a structure
clust_struc(1).Optimalk=optk;
clust_struc(1).method={'CalinskiHarabasz'}
```

I then used code similar to what I have found online:

```
gscatter(x(:,1),x(:,2),E.OptimalY,'rbgckmr','xod*s.p')
%OptimalY is a vector 200 long with the cluster numbers
```

and this is what I get:

[image: clusters]

My question may be silly, but I don't understand why I am only using the first two columns of data to produce the scatter plot? I realise that the clusters themselves are being incorporated through the use of the `Optimal Y`, but should I not be using all of the data in `x`?

Comment: My question may also be silly, but this scatter plot has 2 dimensions, why are you thinking more data is needed? and what would you do with it?

Comment: Well, there's more data in the original data is 200x10, so I was wondering why only the first two variables are included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in `x` is an observation with properties in `size(x,2)` dimensions. All this dimensions are used for clustering `x` rows.

However, when plotting the clusters, we cannot plot more than 2-3 dimensions so we try to represent each element with its key properties. I'm not sure that `x(:,1),x(:,2)` are the best option, but you have to choose 2 for a 2-D plot.

Usually you would have some property of interest that you want to plot. Have a look at the [example in MATLAB doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clustering.evaluation.calinskiharabaszevaluation-class.html#examples): the `fisheriris` data has 4 different variables - the length and width measurements from the sepals and petals of three species of iris flowers. It is up to you to decide which you want to plot against each other (in the example they choosed Petal Length and Petal Width).

Here is a comparison between taking Petals measurements and Sepals measurements as the axis for plotting the grouping:

[image: clustering examples]

Comment: Ah ok. I understand. I thought the other properties were just being ignored, but it's down to the user to identify which variables/properties are the most important in the cluster before plotting this scatterplots. Which leads me to ask another question: the most important or influential variables will be those that differ most between cluster right? Is there a good way to identify these variables? I could use a boxplot using the median for each variable across the clusters I suppose?

Comment: There is no best variables, it is a question of context. The choice should be based on what's informative to you, there are not more important variables than others, but those who contribute more to the clustering. I'm not sure if this method will give you the best axis to choose.

Comment: I should be more clear with my language: when I referred to the most 'influential' variables above, I am referring to those that contribute more to the clustering. So what I'm asking is, how can I identify the variables that make clusters different.ie. the ones that contribute most to creating the partition between two clusters?

Comment: Well, that's an interesting question, which this cluster method won't answer you. You could post another question to address this issue. However, it is more statistical question then programing, so maybe you better ask it [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com)